# ¿Como regresar el valor de un conjunto (Join) entre 2 Listas de la misma clase usando LinQ?

Tags: c#, sql, select, linq, join

En mi proyecto tengo que buscar si un registro existente en 2 tablas sufrió algún cambio en alguno de sus campos para lo que por SQL obtengo el siguiente query:

```
select * from actual a
join nuevo n
on a.idPersona=n.idPersona and a.Nombre = n.Nombre
where (
        a.edad <> n.edad or 
        a.direccion <> n.direccion 
      )
```

al pasarlo a c#:

```
var result = from a in actual 
             join n in nuevo
             on new { a.idPersona, a.Nombre} equals new { n.idPersona, n.Nombre} 
             where !(a.edad == n.edad ) 
             where !(a.direccion == n.direccion) 
             select ¿?;
```

> pero no se de que forma expresar en el ultimo select que me regrese el
> conjunto de la consulta

revidando la documentación disponible solo encuentro ejemplos de relaciones entre tablas distintas y armando un nuevo objeto con los elementos de ambas tablas:

```
var q = from c in db.Customers
        join o in db.Orders on c.CustomerID equals o.CustomerID into orders
        select new { c.ContactName, OrderCount = orders.Count() };
```

Comment: Así mismo es como tienes que hacerlo o bien poner select a y te devolverá todos las propiedades del objeto a

Comment: Pero no de esa forma solamente imprimiría el valor a y no del conjunto?